# Calling vb6 dlls from c#

Tags: c#, vb6, interop

I have been trying to call a vb6 dll from a C sharp application, without using the registry. I want to use the path of the dll while using it. I am unable to create an object of the class of the vb dll. Please help! The code I have written so far is as follows:

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFile("dll path");
Type classType = assem.GetType("classname");
MethodInfo method = classType.GetMethod("show"); //My methos is called show
method.Invoke(null,null); // I have to invoke the method using class object, which I am unable to create
```

Comment: `VB6` DLLs should be `PInvoked`, the way you're currently loading them is for `.NET` DLLs

Comment: @bhavna I'm not sure if you can use VB6 DLL using `Assembly.LoadFile`. Have you tried to call the function using [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)?

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for the tip. But I am very new to c sharp .net framework . Could you please guide me on how the code to call a method from a vb6 dll is to be written in c sharp? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the name of the language is "C#"

Comment: Cab you explain exactly what you mean by "without using the registry"? Do you mean the COM DLL won't be registered at all? Or do you mean that (for some reason) you don't want to add a reference to the COM DLL to your C# project? And additionally can you explain why it has to be that way? Because you are making life quite difficult for yourself, so it would be worth considering whether you can "use the registry" after all.

Comment: @Marco & other close voters We shouldn't close this question yet. This is not a duplicate, because bhavna doesn't want to use the registry. I admit it's hard to answer without knowing *why* bhavna doesn't want to use the registry, but let's please give bhavna a chance to expand before we vote to close the question as "not a real question"

Answer (score 7):

A VB6 DLL is a COM DLL. Usually you would register the DLL (in the registry) and then add a reference to the VB6 DLL from your .NET project.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) gives a walkthrough of using registry-free COM  from a .Net app.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, but these articles provide information about the usage of win32 dlls only :'( I have a vb6 dll to be used in C#.

Comment: The link includes info on .Net clients and VB6 servers. Look at this section, Step 2 part B http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx#rfacomwalk_topic5 and this section http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx#rfacomwalk_topic7. I agree it would be better if the article didn't try to cover C++, C#, VB.Net and VB6 all in one article!

Answer (score 2):

Your VB6 dll as MarkJ mentions is a COM Dll, and they usually need to be registered using regsvr32 before you can use them.

Once it's registered you can add a reference to it the same as you would with a .NET dll, i.e. right click on References in the project, click Add Reference, then select the COM tab on the window and look for your COM Dll name.

Then you should be able to use it like a .NET reference.
Here is an example of how to use a COM reference to Microsoft Excel.
[How to: Use COM Interop to Create an Excel Spreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If you specifically want late binding, then your dll still needs to be registered but you don't manually add a reference, you use Activator.CreateInstance() to get an instance of your COM object.
[Calling COM component from C# using late binding](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/psingh/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp12022005231615PM/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I need to use it by late binding, without using the registry information. Thats the problem!

Comment: Can you give me more detail on your scenario please? Will the dll be registered on the target systems and just not on yours? Because I don't think it's actually possible to use COM dlls without having them registered.

Comment: This article might be relevant  [Registration free activation of COM components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)

Comment: That's the same link I posted in my answer. @bhavna, I think you need to explain *exactly* what you need to do and *why*.  What problem are you trying to solve? *Why* can't you use the registry?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed, I'd just come across it googling.

Comment: @Mark - Two or more dlls may have the same name. If I use registry information, the system would automatically use the last registered dll with the same name. This is something I do not want. I need the dll to be used by giving its file path rather than registry.

Comment: @bhavna Then you need registry-free COM. See the [link in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9257878/15639). Or, and it might be simpler, just make sure you only have one DLL registered. When you create new versions of the DLL, make sure they are backward compatible with the older versions. Use "binary compatibility" in the VB6 project settings to keep the syntax and COM interfaces constant, and make sure not to change the contract / semantics of your DLL.

Comment: Thanks @Mark! Will try what you have suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the method `show` is in the export table in the dll, try using `DllImportAttribute` to call the show method.

Comment: 99 times out of 100 a VB6 DLL will not expose anything useful through the export table. They are COM DLls. (*Rarely* a DLL author would use blackbelt techniques to export functions as if the DLL was an old-style DLL.)

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the code required to do the same?

Comment: And how should I put the method in export table?

Comment: For eg. you can call windows sendmessage in user32.dll from managed code  [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]       
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public void yourMethod()
{
SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
} and this can be done only if the dll has the method in export table.

Comment: Registry-free COM will be **much simpler** than exporting methods through the export table in VB6 and then trying to P/Invoke them from .Net. That's seriously advanced stuff.

Comment: What if you don't know the methods inside the DLL? I've simply referenced it directly into my project and I can see its methods and functions, etc in the Object Browser.