# How to create a new instance of a class from a DLL?

Tags: vb.net, dllimport

I am converting an old application coded with `VB6` to `VB.NET`.

In my old application I was using a third party `DLL` file. Let's call it `ThirdParty.dll`.

One of my usages of that `ThirdParty.DLL` was like that in `VB6`:

```
Dim MyApi as new x.y 'referenced from the ThirdParty.dll
Dim vReturnCode as Long

vReturnCode = MyAPI.InitialiserCles(a, b, c, d, e) 'consider a,b,c,d,e variables declared and initiaited.
```

In the old application, this would return a result as `Long`.

Now, I need to use that same `ThirdParty.dll` in my new `VB.NET` application.

What I created was this:

```
Public Class ThirdPartyAPI
    Private Declare Function InitialiserCles Lib "ThirdPartyFolder\ThirdParty" (a As String, b As String, c As String, d As String, ByRef e As String) As Long

    Public Function InitializeKey(a As String, b As String, c As String, d As String, ByRef e As String) As Long
        Return InitialiserCles(a, b, c, d, e)

    End Function
End Class
```

Now when I want to use that, I am doing it like this:

```
Dim MyApi as new ThirdPartyAPI
Dim result as MyApi.InitialiserCles(a,b,c,d,e) 'consider again variables are well declared/initiated.
```

I am getting the following error:

> Can't find DLL entry point 'InitialiserCles' in DLL ThirdPartyFolder\ThirdParty

I guess this is happening because we were actually creating a new instance of `x.y` from that DLL, then calling the function `InitialiserCles` (in the old applciation (VB6)). I failed to do the same in `VB.NET`. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like the DLL is actually a COM library. I suggest that you study the original code more closely so that you understand it. Also well worth consulting the documentation for that DLL.

Comment: I do think it's a COM library as well. I've already checked the documentation for that DLL, it only explains how to use it with VB6, and it gives the signatures of the functions.

Comment: So, if you know it's a COM library, why are you using `Declare`? Not only is that only for legacy code (p/invoke is now the way), it's no good for COM. I think what you need is not an SO question, but some good old fashioned research into the problem space.

Comment: When I tried to add it as a reference in the .net project, I get the error that it's not a valid assembly or COM component. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: You can't add a VB6 DLL as a reference to a .net project directly. You need an interop assembly to do the talking between COM and .NET. See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9258238/1188513) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this my first time working with COM DLLs and other stuff, it wasn't easy for me. Thanks for the comments above I was able to do it.

What ended up working for me was the next:

Since ThirdParty.DLL was a COM DLL I had to register it using `regsvr32` command. **Note that I had to use the one located inside `SysWOW64` for it to work.** Obviously because it's a 32 bit DLL file. The command then is:

```
regsvr32 "FullPath\ThirdParty"
```

After running this command successfully, from visual studio I was able to add a reference from com objects called ThirdParty and then I was able to create instance of classes from that DLL.